# What is the rarity of a Shield Guardian?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting

Shield Guardian says :

> Wizards and other spellcasters create shield guardians for protection.

So I want to craft a Shield Guardian for my Wizard. The description of shield guardians seems like these items are a trading commodity for wizards. What is the rarity so I can use XGTE crafting rules to create one? I assume I'll have to create the Master's Amulet afterwards.

Comment: Related: [What is the rarity of an amulet of a shield guardian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116966/28591) this is mainly for AL but some rules apply generally.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose In AL its unique in normal D&D Next its rare according to D&D Beyond

Comment: That is indeed what the answer I wrote there says. But I am not sure why you are telling me this? If you think this is a possible answer to your question you can write it as one and post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 10):

## There is no rarity.

The terms for rarity are defined in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* for magic items. The Shield Guardian is a creature, not an object (items are objects). Therefore there is no defined way to assign it a rarity based on those terms.

But, more importantly...

## There are no rules for creating a Shield Guardian.

As of this posting, there are no rules in 5e for creating a Shield Guardian. The rules for crafting in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* are for crafting items and magic items, not creatures. This means that creating a Shield Guardian is entirely a matter of DM rulings or homebrew.

For example, it would be reasonable for a DM to look at the rules for the *manual of golems* magic item in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 180-181) for inspiration. The rules list the time and cost to make a particular kind of golem in the *Monster Manual*, and these expenses increase with the challenge rating (CR) of the golem. The DM could create a *manual of Shield Guardians* with comparable expenses based on the Shield Guardian's CR 7 in relation to the golems, plus the effort and expense of creating the amulet to control it.