# Are there any rules on the creation of a shield guardian?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, crafting

Are there any rules related to the creation of a [shield guardian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shield-guardian)?

I am aware of the creation method for the amulet. But I'm asking about creating the actual construct.

Comment: I've been curious about this myself, TX for asking!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No, the shield guardian has no specific creation instructions

Unfortunately, as of yet, the published 5e resources contain no instructions or indication as to what is required to actually construct a shield guardian. There are a couple of different downtime rulesets you can use for crafting magical items (as seen in [the DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/between-adventures#CraftingaMagicItem) and in [Xanathar's Guide to Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem)), but these both depend on knowing the item's rarity (which is not given for a shield guardian), and anyway a shield guardian isn't an *item*, it is a *creature*.

As Bloodcinder suggests in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122322/28402) to a related question, a DM who wants to enable their player to create a shield guardian could refer to an existing magical item, the [*manual of golems*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/manual-of-golems), which enables construction of thematically very similar creatures:

> For example, it would be reasonable for a DM to look at the rules for the *manual of golems* magic item in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 180-181) for inspiration. The rules list the time and cost to make a particular kind of golem in the *Monster Manual*, and these expenses increase with the challenge rating (CR) of the golem. The DM could create a *manual of Shield Guardians* with comparable expenses based on the Shield Guardian's CR 7 in relation to the golems, plus the effort and expense of creating the amulet to control it.

Besides the spell [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) (which can only create a construct that is a duplicate of an existing beast or humanoid), the *manual of golems* is the only method given for creating magical constructs. Using this as reference, one would figure that creating a shield guardian should cost between 50,000-65,000gp and take somewhere between 30 and 60 days of effort (falling as it does between the CR 5 flesh golem and the CR 9 clay golem) as well as requiring the use of a specific manual.

Comment: While not a rule per se, https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Shield_guardian has some notes on their construction that could be useful.  Also, the spell *Simulacrum* creates a construct that *(via Illusion magic)* looks like the caster.

Comment: @aaron9eee the FR wiki's notes about construction refer to the 3/3.5e version of the [shield guardian](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/shieldGuardian.htm), which does indeed describe how such a creature can be constructed in that edition's magical crafting rules.